# Merger/join two tables, missing information from second tables

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

The df1 I have

```
OBJECTID    County  State   WeightedAverage
0   1   Allegan MI  33.088148
1   2   Arenac  MI  15.000000
2   3   Branch  MI  43.000000
3   4   Calhoun MI  12.931455
4   5   Charlevoix  MI  7.679045
```

The df2 I have

```
    County  ConfirmedCases  ConfirmedDeaths ProbableCases   TotalCases  TotalDeaths Weighed_Pos Weighed_Death   OBJECTID    ProbableDeaths  PrevTotCases    PrevTotDeaths   Population  Shape__Area Shape__Length
0   Eaton   7657    159 1042    8699    167 0.078908    0.001515    1   8   8265    164 110243  16150919896 5.079141e+05
1   Alcona  475 21  96  571 26  0.053018    0.002414    2   5   539 25  10770   19379884867 5.663069e+05
2   Alger   295 1   177 472 5   0.051121    0.000542    3   4   462 5   9233    26217416016 1.285307e+06
3   Allegan 8124    97  952 9076    120 0.074833    0.000989    4   23  8738    118 121283  23483935830 6.319381e+05
4   Alpena  1468
    51  307 1775    52  0.061853
```

The information is not important, I can clearly see Allegan appeared in both tables, however when I joint the two tables together.
`df=pd.merge(q1w, co, on='County', how='left')`

I got all NA from second table.

```
    OBJECTID_x  County  State   WeightedAverage ConfirmedCases  ConfirmedDeaths ProbableCases   TotalCases  TotalDeaths Weighed_Pos Weighed_Death   OBJECTID_y  ProbableDeaths  PrevTotCases    PrevTotDeaths   Population  Shape__Area Shape__Length
0   1   Allegan MI  33.088148   NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
1   2   Arenac  MI  15.000000   NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
2   3   Branch  MI  43.000000   NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
3   4   Calhoun MI  12.931455   NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
```

Comment: Are there any leading/trailing spaces in the `County` column in one dataframe or the other?

Answer (score 1):

I believe that there might be blank spaces in County column.
Try removing them `merged = pd.merge(df1, df2, on='County', how='left')` and then `merged.County = merged.County.apply(lambda cty: cty.strip())`